# can i develop Android, Iphone, Windows application using cakePHP?

Tags: ios, cakephp

I'm trying to develop Apps for Iphone and Windows. (Maybe for android later). 
So can i use cakePHP, maybe JavaScrips with it to develop fully functional 
Applications? 
P.S. Please try to explain in simple words so dummy like me can understand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, there are two ways to develop a mobile app :

1. Use the native language of your target platform (Objective-C for iOS, Java for Android, etc..).
   Performances will be good, but you will have to develop your app for each platform separately (assuming you know each native language...), that can be a very long work (sometimes necessary).
2. Use a cross platform framework, as Phonegap/Cordova.
   Performance won't as good as if you build your app using a native language, but you will be able to deploy it on every platform you want. No native language knowledge are required because you will use HTML and Javascript to develop your app.

PHP is a server side language, so it won't be very helpful to build your app. However, you can still use it to develop a server application which can interact with your mobile app (store some data in a database, use the server's CPU to do some stuff, etc...).

Good luck !

Some reading :

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/RoadMapiOS/

http://phonegap.com/

Comment: You're welcome, you can check the response if it's good for you.